# Checking if someone has a role in DiscordJS is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, discord, discord.js

I have a embed with buttons and I want to check if someone has a role.

```
case "lock":
    if(!guild.members.me.roles.cache.some((r) => r.id === docs.Handlers))
        return interaction.reply({content: "You don't have the permissions for that", ephemeral: true});

    if(data.Locked == true)
        return interaction.reply({content: "Ticket is already locked.", ephemeral: true});
                    
    await ticketSchema.updateOne({ChannelID: channel.id}, {Locked: true});
    embed.setDescription("The ticket has been locked successfully!");

    data.MembersID.forEach((m) => {
        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(m, {SendMessages: false});
    });

    return interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
```

The first IF is what bothers me.

Here is the "docs" variable.

```
const docs = await TicketSetup.findOne({GuildID: guild.id});
```

And the TicketSetup part:
`Handlers: String,`

I have a separate command that is used to set the Handlers as a role in the server.

```
.addRoleOption(option =>
    option.setName("handlers")
    .setDescription("Select the ticket handlers role.")
    .setRequired(true)
)
......
const handlers = options.getRole("handlers");
......
Handlers: handlers.id,
```

I want to make that if someone doesn't have a docs.Handlers role it says "You don't have a perm...", but if someone does have it, it should work for him. I'm guessing that I'm not using the if statement correctly but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=me), `guild.members.me` is:

> The client user as a GuildMember of this guild

This means that you're checking your bot's own permisisons instead of the user's.

In order to check the user's permissions, you'll want to use `interaction.member`:

```js
if(!interaction.member.roles.cache.some((r) => r.id === docs.Handlers))
```

If this fails, the member might not be in cache, and you'll need to fetch it first.

Aditionally, as @Jiralite mentioned in the comments, you can use `.has()`, which will do the same thing as `.some((r) => r.id === docs.Handlers)`:

```js
if(!interaction.member.roles.cache.has(docs.Handlers))
```

Comment: I'd like to add that one can use `.has()` instead of `.some()`: `interaction.member.roles.cache.has(docs.Handlers)`

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll add that to the answer too. Thanks!